# How to convert a POST to a url?

Tags: php, post, input, http-post

Is possible to send data, that you normal have to use a submit button to send it, by using just the url?

Here is an example of code from a site with a button like that:

```
<form method="POST" action="Action.php?action=338&amp;n=688&amp;t=mine"><input type="hidden" id="Mine688" value="1" name="duree"><button value="submit" class="boutonsGeneral" type="submit" name="travail"><span title="" class="infoBoutonsGeneral"><span class="boutonsGeneral_separateur">&nbsp;</span><span class="boutonsGeneral_gain" id="gainMine688"><img width="48" height="24" src="images/items/itemArgent.png">+2,18</span></span>Munca <span class="boutonsGeneral_duree boutonsGeneral_dureeMoins" id="dureeMine688">1 hour</span></button></form>
```

[image]

This is from Live HTTP Header when I click on that button:

```
ww.kraljevine.com/Action.php?action=338&n=688&t=mine

POST /Action.php?action=338&n=688&t=mine HTTP/1.1
Host: ww.kraljevine.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ro-ro,ro;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.6,en-gb;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: ww.kraljevine.com/EcranPrincipal.php?l=8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ec95ed7caf7c28f8a333; KC=account_name; KC2=1502cae30e04f5f55963e93; > > Glup=274; pageTamponVue=1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 22
duree=1&travail=submit
```

What I want to do is to send the post by url. Something like:

http://www.kraljevine.com/Action.php?action=338&n=688&t=mine (untill here is the link from site, and I want to add this) duree=1&travail=submit
Is not working http://www.kraljevine.com/Action.php?action=338&n=688&t=mine&duree=1&travail=submit and because of this I am wondering if is possible to do this.

Comment: You can use cURL to send post-paramters.

Comment: Use method GET man. It's much simpler. Using get you have the variables shown in url.

Comment: Complicating things for no reason. If the parameter go in the QUERYSTRING use GET, if they go on a form use POST. It´s that simple and both aways are accessed the same way in php code.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to know what **POST** and **GET** are used for.

- If you want to **SEND** data you should use **POST**
- If you want to **GET** data depending on some params then use **GET**.

There is no sense in sending data with **GET** there are also some limitations to this. You can read more about limits **[here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1)**.

You can always use **CURL** to send **POST** data to the other URL.

[Here is good tutorial how to do it](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post) and here goes the example based on this tutorial:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.kraljevine.com/Action.php?action=338&n=688&t=mine';
$fields = array(
                    'duree' => urlencode('1'),
                    'travail' => urlencode('submit')
            ); 
//$fields can be extended with more params for POST submit always encode them with urlencode for these 2 examples of 1 submit it is not necessary but sometimes is really imporant to do it

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The last thing is `$_REQUEST` which is *An associative array that by default contains the contents of **$_GET**, **$_POST** and **$_COOKIE**.* You can use it in php script and there will be no difference how the variable is passed for php script.

Use it wisely.

Answer (score 1):

make the form method GET and put the variables in hidden fields in your form.
for example:

```
<form method="GET" action="Action.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="338" />
 <input type="hidden" name="n" value="688" />
 <input type="hidden" name="t" value="mime" />
 ...more html/php...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

By definition, GET variables are sent in the URL,
and POST variables are sent in the request's body.

So, you can't send your variables JUST by using the URL, as you requested.

You probably can physically catch a possible URL with parameters even in POST request, but I highly recommend you not the takes this approach.

You can read more about it in [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm) post

Answer (score 0):

In my case using spring boot.
I have converted from POST to GET like this :

**BEFORE**

in jsp( sender ):

[image]

in Java (reveiver):
[image]

I have converted to :

**AFTER**

in Jsp:
[image]

in Java:
[image]

and the result is match to what I want. I have changed only where the arrow is pointed in the picture, it saves my time a lot. All parameters will be composed into object "searchModel" easily.

[image]